# subprocess.call open terminal and just flahing out? (Windows)

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I've been trying this `subprocess.call` in my PC/Windows, and wonder how to make it working?  Thanks for your help and tips.  (I've been searching and cannot find anything related yet...)

So this is the code in my Python shell: (everything work to the point at my typing of `beef` in newly open `terminal`. Then the terminal window just flashing out/disappearing?)

```py
>>> import subprocess

>>> subprocess.call('python check_words.py')
0  

# A new window terminal opening and prompt as the check_words.py asking for a word:
What is the word:
beef                     # my typing

# window terminal disappearing?  
# my python shell window exit code `0`   meaning `ok`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two ways for this purpose `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.call`

`Popen` doesn't block, allowing you to interact with the process while it's running, or continue with other things in your Python program. The call to `Popen` returns a Popen object

`call` does block. While it supports all the same arguments as the Popen constructor, so you can still set the process' output, environmental variables, etc., your script waits for the program to complete, and `call` returns a code representing the process' exit status

```
from sys import executable
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

Popen([executable, 'check_words.py'], creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
input('Enter to exit')
```

OR same you can do with using string argument with keyword argument `shell = True` but this is an dangerous way of doing: [implications](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/162938/security-implications-of-suprocess-executing-with-a-active-shell-vs-no-shell)

```
Popen('check_words.py',shell = true, creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

The same you can try with `call` as well and it you give you the same result